# How to disable jquery validate when form is submitted?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Just want to have a partial Save function on my page.

so when a user clicks on **Save for Later**, no validation is performed. While a click on **Save and Submit** will trigger the validation before the form is submitted.

The buttons are:

```
<button type="submit" name="Action" value="SaveForLater">Save for Later</button>
<button type="submit" name="Action" value="SaveAndSubmit">Save and Submit</button>
```

I have the `validate()` function in place already.

```
$('#formEdit').validate({
    rules: ..,
    messages: ...,
    ignore: ...,
});
```

How can I by pass `validate` when **Save for Later** is clicked?

Comment: So you want to save invalid data?

Comment: Allow saving when some required fields are not supplied.

Comment: Okay that makes sense

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate.` <input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Cancel">`